# Prove there exists an element in the function...Beginning function proof

Tags: functions

Having trouble with the last part of my proof:

Let f: $\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ be a function with $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$ for all $x,y \in \mathbb{Z}$. 
Prove there exists an element $a\in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $f(n)=na$ for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

What do I do? I was thinking of combining $na$ into $q$ and then $f(n)=q$.

### But then that means that $n$ divides $q$. Where do I start?

So if my base case is n=1, then the induction hypothesis must prove true for f(k) = ka. Then in my induction step f(k+1)=(k+1)(a) and what do I do next? I feel like I proved it because there does exist an a.

Comment: So if my base case is n=1, then the induction hypothesis must prove true for f(k) = ka. Then in my induction step f(k+1)=(k+1)(a) and what do I do next? I feel like I proved it because there does exist an a.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** Let $a = f(1)$.  Then $f(n) = na$ holds for $n = 1$.  Use that as a base case in an induction proof.

Comment: So if my base case is n=1, then the induction hypothesis must prove true for f(k) = ka. Then in my induction step f(k+1)=(k+1)(a) and what do I do next? I feel like I proved it because there does exist an a.

Comment: For the induction hypothesis you assume that $f(n) = na$ (for just that particular $n$, not for all $n$).  Then you use $f(x + y) = f(x) + f(y)$ to show that $f(n + 1) = (n + 1)a$.  After you've done that you're done with the induction and you say that therefore $f(n) = na$ holds for all $n$.